# Java 8 Stream Map Reduce

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I'm totally new on java 8 streams and I'm trying to obtain the behavior below described:

```
class myVO {
    Long id;
    BigDecimal value;
    Date date;
    getter/setter
}

myVO method(Map<Long, myVO> inputMap) {
    return inputMap.stream()
                   .filter(x -> x.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
                   .sorted(); //FIXME
}
```

I want to obtain only one `myVO` obj that is the SUM of `BigDecimal` values of the records with the same date (the lowest one).

e.g.

```
xL, 10, 2015/07/07
xL, 15, 2015/07/08
xL, 20, 2015/07/07
xL, 25, 2015/07/09
```

result

```
xL, 30, 2015/07/07
```

N.B. id (xL) is not important field.

UPDATE -- adopted solution (although not in single pass)

```
if(null != map && !map.isEmpty()) {
        Date closestDate = map.values().stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getDate() != null)
                .map(MyVO::getDate)
                .min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
        myVO.setDate(closestDate);

        BigDecimal totalValue = map.values().stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getValue() != null && x.getValue().signum() != 0)
                .filter(t -> t.getDate().equals(closestDate))
                .map(MyVO::getValue)
                .reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(null);
        myVO.setValue(totalValue != null ? totalValue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN) : totalValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering inputMap has atleast one entry, it can be done like this :

```
myVO method(Map<Long, myVO> inputMap) {
    Date minDate = inputMap.values().stream().map(myVO::getDate).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();

    BigDecimal sum = inputMap.values().stream().filter(t -> t.getDate().equals(minDate)).map(myVO::getValue).reduce(BigDecimal::add).get();

    myVO myVOObj = new myVO();
    myVOObj.setDate(minDate);
    myVOObj.setValue(sum);
    myVOObj.setId(??);

    return myVOObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom collector to solve such tasks. It's available in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library and called [`MoreCollectors.maxAll(downstream)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#maxAll-java.util.stream.Collector-). Using it you can solve the task in single pass after some preparations.

First, your `compareTo` method is wrong. It never returns 0 and practically it violates the contract (`a.compareTo(a) == -1` which violates reflexivity and antisymmetry properties). It can be easily fixed like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(myVO o) {
    return o.getDate().compareTo(this.getDate());
}
```

Next, let's add a `myVO.merge()` method which can merge two `myVO` objects according to your requirements:

```
public myVO merge(myVO other) {
    myVO result = new myVO();
    result.setId(getId());
    result.setDate(getDate());
    result.setValue(getValue().add(other.getValue()));
    return result;
}
```

Now the result can be found like this:

```
Optional<myVO> result = input.stream().filter(x -> x.getValue().signum() > 0)
    .collect(MoreCollectors.maxAll(Collectors.reducing(myVO::merge)));
```

The resulting `Optional` will be empty if the input list is empty.

If you don't like to depend on third-party library, you can just check the [source code](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/11afb51cf1baa512218cc9889410de15150d9907/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.java#L209) of this collector and write something similar in your project.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction isn’t that complicated if you think about it. You have to specify a reduction function which:

- if the dates of two elements differ, returns the object with the lower date
- if they match, create a result object containing the sum of the values

Compared to a two-step method, it may perform more `add` operations whose result will be dropped when a lower date appears in the stream, on the other hand, the number of performed date comparisons will be half.

```
MyVO method(Map<Long, MyVO> inputMap) {
    return inputMap.values().stream()
        .reduce((a,b)->{
            int cmp=a.getDate().compareTo(b.getDate());
            if(cmp==0)
            {
                MyVO r=new MyVO();
                r.setDate(a.date);
                r.setValue(a.value.add(b.value));
                return r;
            }
            return cmp<0? a: b;
        }).orElse(null);
}
```

The main reason it doesn’t look concise is that it has to create a new `MyVO` instance holding the sum in the case of a matching date as a reduction function *must not* modify the value objects. And you didn’t specify which constructors exist. If there is an appropriate constructor receiving a `Date` and `BigDecimal`, the function could be almost a one-liner.

Note that this method will return an original `MyVO` object if there is only a single one with a lowest date.

---

Alternatively you can use a mutable reduction, always creating a new `MyVO` instance holding the result but only creating one instance per thread and modifying that new instance during the reduction:

```
MyVO method(Map<Long, MyVO> inputMap) {
    BiConsumer<MyVO, MyVO> c=(a,b)->{
        Date date = a.getDate();
        int cmp=date==null? 1: date.compareTo(b.getDate());
        if(cmp==0) a.setValue(a.getValue().add(b.getValue()));
        else if(cmp>0)
        {
            a.setValue(b.getValue());
            a.setDate(b.getDate());
        }
    };
    return inputMap.values().stream().collect(()->{
        MyVO r = new MyVO();
        r.setValue(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        return r;
    }, c, c);
}
```

Here, the `Supplier` could be a one-line if an appropriate constructor exists (or if the initial value is guaranteed to be the non-`null` `BigDecimal.ZERO`)…